# How do I distinguish $\rm m$ for "meter" and $m$ for "mass"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, conventions, notation, si-units

For example, an object in height 10 meters has 60 Joules of potential energy.

PE = mgh
60 J = m⋅(9.8 m/s²)(10m)
60 J = m⋅(98 m²/s²)
m ≈ 0.6

How can I distinguish it?

Comment: Always algebraically separate the unknown variable first, then substitute units, as Billy Istiak has shown you below.  Your method mixes variables and units, confuses you, and allows you to use a calculator to back calculate the unknown without using any algebra ... which is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, people write the quantities in italics, unlike the units.

$$\begin{align}\text{GPE}&= mgh\\60\text{ J}&= m \cdot(9.8 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2)\cdot(10\text{ m})\\&= m\cdot(98 \text{ m}^2/\text{s}^2)\\m&\approx 0.6\text{ kg}\end{align}$$

In LaTeX, type the quantities in math mode: `$m$` yields $m$ (meaning mass). To type units inside the math mode, use, for example, `$10\text{ m}` or `$10\,\mathrm{m}$`, which yields $10\text{ m}$.

Comment: Explicit upright type is acceptable for short-form text. For anything long enough to be a full LaTeX document, the preferred option is to use the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package and its associated syntax `\SI{10}{m}`.

Answer (score 4):

The authoritative reference for the SI is the official BIPM brochure on the SI:

https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9.pdf/fcf090b2-04e6-88cc-1149-c3e029ad8232?version=1.16&t=1632138652324&download=true

On p 147 it states “Unit symbols are printed in upright type regardless of the type used in the surrounding text”. So using any other typeface for variables will allow them to be distinguished.

On p 148 it says specifically “Symbols for quantities are generally single letters set in an italic font”, which is the standard practice and should generally be followed. This helps readers to understand at a glance which quantities mean what. Readers will instantly recognize that $5 \ m$ is five times some variable $m$ and that $5\mathrm{\ m}$ is 5 meters. Any other typeface conventions should be made explicit.

Finally, p 149 says “The numerical value always precedes the unit and a space is always used to separate the unit from the number”. That can also be helpful by grouping any units together with a space after the quantity to add visual separation.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/694615/315444) is correct. But I will rearrange equation before setting down values.

$$W=mgh$$

Let I know W, g and h but I don't know mass, so I want to find it. Write

$$m=\frac{W}{gh}$$
then put all your values it won't confuse. For two unknown equations, I suggest to plug them before putting values then put values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the situation of m(meter) and m (mass) is different. m(meter) will appear in the unit of quantity, but m(mass) will not. If there are special cases, we usually use “*m*” in italics to represent mass, and the other represents mass.
Of course, in certain cases, you can also use uppercase "M" to represent quality and lowercase "m" to represent meters.

Comment: Usually it is the opposite, $m$ in italics for mass and "m" for meters.

Comment: I see that you changed "meters" to "mass" in one place but you forgot to change "mass" to "meters" in the other place.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too careless. I'm always careless. I'll get rid of this problem in the future.